# Encrypting data from file and sending on a socket via MemoryStream( byte[] ) using C# / .Net

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, asyncsocket

We have a sockets server that needs to transfer *encrypted* binary files to connected clients.
The files need to be encrypted when requests for them arrive, preferably **without** making encrypted copies of files on disk first.

Due to the fact that we use asynchronous sockets API, Sockets.NetworkStream **cannot** be used. Instead, we need to utilize Socket.BeginSend() with a byte[] buffer as the input.

A seemingly straight forward possibility is to use CryptoStream with a MemoryStream as its destination for encrypted content. MemoryStream itself would use a byte [] buffer as its own data repository.

For example:

```
int blockSizeBytes = 1024 * 64;
byte [] plainData = new byte [blockSizeBytes];
byte [] encData = new byte [blockSizeBytes];
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream( encData );

ICryptoTransform encryptor = ... any ***CryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor();
CryptoStream csEnc = new CryptoStream( memory, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write );
```

A file can be read and encrypted a buffer at a time, which would then be sent over the socket to the client. For example:

```
Socket clientSocket = ...; // connected peer.
int bytesRead = 0;
FileStream streamIn = new FileStream( strInputFile, FileMode.Open );
do
{
    bytesRead = streamIn.Read( plainData , 0, blockSizeBytes );
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        csEnc.Write( plainData , 0, bytesRead );   // Write to crypto stream

        // At this point the underlying byte array encData will hold the most recently
        // encrypted buffer of data.

        // Ideally we would send the encData buffer over the socket to the client via 
        // the following pseudo-code:

        // 1) How can we determine the precise number of encoded bytes to send?
        clientSocket.BeginSend( encData, 0, bytesRead, ... /* other params */ );

        ...

        memory.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );  // Reset memory stream back to start
    }
}
while (bytesRead > 0);

streamIn.Close();  // close intput file stream

outEnc.FlushFinalBlock();  // Deal with padding, etc.

// Send the final buffer with all the necessary padding to the client.
// 2) Again, how can we determine the exact number of encoded bytes to send?
clientSocket.BeginSend( encData, 0, ??how-many-bytes??, ... );

outEnc.Close();
```

For testing purposes we wrote out the encoded buffers to file instead of the socket. When trying to decrypt the resulting file, the following exception is thrown: **CryptographicException: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.**

As can be seen in items 1) and 2) above, we don't know the precise number of encoded bytes to transfer to the client (or save to a file). We tried memory.Position as the buffer size after FlushFinalBlock(), though without success.

Please note, when CryptoStream is using a FileStream for its output, i.e., neither MemoryStream nor byte[] buffers are used, the resulting file is encrypted normally and then subsequently decrypted successfully. Our goal, though, is to be able to write out encrypted byte[] buffers directly without output streams.

If MemoryStream with byte[] buffer is not feasible, are there other alternatives to be able to incrementally encrypt buffers and forward them on, e.g., socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this using `memory.Position` as the `Count` parameter in both `clientSocket.BeginSend(...)` methods, and was able to round-trip (i.e. encrypt then decrypt the encrypted data) successfully. If this isn't working for you, it'd be worth providing code for a complete, self-contained, compilable example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Using memory.Position in **both** 1) and 2) solved it for us. Before we used .Position only after FlushFinalBlock(). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After the clarification by [Iridium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18321738/858339) above, the following is a fully functioning chunk of code that uses MemoryStream with byte[] buffers to encrypt binary data from an input file and write out the resulting encrypted data to an output file:

```
...
RijndaelManaged rjndl = new RijndaelManaged() 
{ KeySize = 128, BlockSize = 128, Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 };

int blockSizeBytes = 1024 * 64; // blockSizeBytes can be any arbitrary size.
byte [] data = new byte [blockSizeBytes];
byte [] encData = new byte [blockSizeBytes];
int bytesRead = 0;

ICryptoTransform encryptor = rjndl.CreateEncryptor( keyIVBytes, keyIVBytes );

FileStream streamOut = new FileStream( strOutputFile, FileMode.Create );
FileStream streamIn = new FileStream( strInputFile, FileMode.Open );

MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream( encData );
CryptoStream outEnc = new CryptoStream( memory, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write );

do
{
    bytesRead = streamIn.Read( data, 0, blockSizeBytes );

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        outEnc.Write( data, 0, bytesRead );
        streamOut.Write( encData, 0, (int)memory.Position );
        memory.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
    }
} while (bytesRead > 0);

streamIn.Close();

outEnc.FlushFinalBlock();
streamOut.Write( encData, 0, (int)memory.Position );

outEnc.Close();
streamOut.Close();
...
```